How to use iptables to forward a loopback IP to an external ip address?
I have a service that is using ports 5000 5001 5002 5010 5020 on a loopback IP, 127.1.7.131 on my local machine. I need to create a tcp connection to these ports on the loopback IP from an external server. My local machine has the external IP of 10.25.1.141. I am trying to use iptables rules to create this port forwarding. I created the following bash script to set up the port forwarding.
ip=127.1.7.131
ports=( 5000 5001 5002 5010 5020 )
for port in ${ports[@]}; do
    iptables -$cmd FORWARD -p tcp --dport $port -d $ip -j ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -$cmd PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $ip:$port
    iptables -t nat -$cmd OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $ip:$port
done

I am testing using the command nc -vz 10.25.1.141 5000. Before running my bash script, the nc command responds "connection refused" on my local machine. After running the script, the nc command responds "open" on my local machine. Howvever running the same command on the external server responds "connection timed out". Running nc -vz 10.25.1.141 22 on the external server returns "connection successful" so I know the two servers can connect

Check out the route_localnet sysctl

Found the solution with the help of Tom Yan. I had to add iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport $port -j ACCEPT
as well as
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
